# Could somebody correct this join query?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM {$dbp}auctions au, ic.imgurl 
LEFT JOIN {$dbp}cache ic ON au.cache_id = ic.id
```

I'm baffled on where to set the alias for the second table (`ic`) and still only select the one column (`imgurl`).

Comment: Thanks for the downvote :) Wouldn't expect anything less from you guys :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"SELECT au.*, ic.imgurl FROM {$dbp}auctions au  
LEFT JOIN {$dbp}cache ic ON au.cache_id = ic.id"
```

I think this is close to what you want. Your original query is selecting everything.